# Use read-only database user to minimize security risks

Tags: database, 6, security

I want to phase out an old, unmaintained Drupal 6 page. The website should still stay online, but should be read-only.

I want to change the database user so that it only has `read` privileges. I don't want the website to be exploitable due to any security issue in Drupal 6 or any of the modules.

Is it possible to give Drupal 6 a read-only database user? On which table is write access necessary?

Comment: May be use httrack to get static pages and host it somewhere and redirect to the static site.

Answer (score 0):

You can make [make read only tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861564/make-a-single-table-in-mysql-read-only), except: `semaphor, watchdog, cache, cache_[ANOTHERS], sessions`, and another tables, depend on installed modules, that can modify tables on guests visiting, login or form submissions, like statistics, flag and so on.

But I strongly **DO NOT** recommend this, because instead of showing read only site you may show white or errors screen.

Better is use [Read only mode](https://www.drupal.org/project/readonlymode) module, that make site read only (prevent form submissions and so on).

Another solution - make backup, then restore 1 per day via bash script. [Samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027832/i-need-to-restore-a-database-mysql-every-30-minutes-using-a-cron-job).

Answer (score 0):

For a site where users cannot login, read-only access to the database is possible if none of the modules:

- Saves data in the database
- Stores data in the user session
- Caches data
- Uses the locking system implemented by Drupal core
- Saves or deletes persistent variables
- Logs errors

If the purpose is just avoiding the Drupal site writes on the database, it's possible to provide a different implementation for session handlers, cache, and lock system that stores data in Memcached, but the data would not persist as in a database. (This could be the desired effect, if the site isn't supposed to store the data for anonymous users for much long.)
The data stored from `watchdog()` can be stored in the system Syslog, if instead of the *Database logging* module the site uses the *Syslog* module.
As for storing data in the session, keep in mind that even a call to `drupal_set_message()` causes Drupal to add data in the session.

Otherwise, for a partial read-only access to the database, the following database tables should be writable.

- cache
- cache_*
- semaphore
- sessions
- variable (This is the database table where the values submitted in a form could be saved, especially setting values.)
- watchdog, if the *Database logging* module is enabled
- Any database table the installed modules use to write data

Answer (score 0):

You could have a module like [Boost](https://www.drupal.org/project/boost) or similar generate a static version of the site and then just serve that and decommission the database - unless you have some dynamic/ajax action happening. You could also dump the site with a tool like [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/).